# Retaining CSS when changing text dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to randomize a number with a button, but every time I clicked the button, the number randomizes, but the text loses it's CSS style.

CSS

```
.numberStyle {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: blue;
}

.numberStyle span {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Html

```
<class id="number1" class="numberStyle"><span>1</span></class>
<input type="button" value="MATCH!" style="font-size:50px;"></input>
```

Javascript

```
function randomize() {
  no1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
}

function print() {
  $("#number1").text(no1);
}

$().ready(function() {

  $(":input").click(function() {
    randomize()
    print()
    alert("Change")
  })

})
```

my JSFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/he4rtbr0ken/9jfud4nz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting the parent of the `<span>` element and then changing its text which is essentially removing the span and replacing it with only the number. You can fix this by targeting the span or including the span in the text you are adding.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the text within the span rather than #number1

```
function print() {
    $("span").text(no1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's more than one `span` on the page. The selector isn't specific enough.

Comment: The point of a span is the same as any other tag, which is to categorize. If they need more specificity they should consider to either add a class or use a different tag all together. This answer is the most direct with the given information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer!

I've targeted `<span>` element and it works.

replaced `print()` function with the codes below.

```
function print() {
  $("#number1 > span").text(no1);
}
```